# Error 500 Tag Manager Server Google Cloud

Tags: cloud

I created my server automatically via google tag manager, and when trying to access my default url I'm getting this error:

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Can anyone help me with this? I've already checked the entire server and because it was created automatically, all the settings are ok.

I checked my error report and this is showing:

Error: Fetching container from https://www.googletagmanager.com/server.js?id=XXXXXXX&gtm_preview=env-1&gtm_auth=XXXXXXXX failed: Received HTTP status code 404.
undefined. ( evalmachine.:27 )

Comment: Hmmm.  Same, I bet there is some GCP account related issue that isn't surfacing up to GTM. I'm getting 500 errors though, which is suspicious status code if it's some account issue.

Comment: OK my suspicion was correct. Turns out, way in in my GCP dashboard I had a failed charge of $0.01. There were no (obvious) project level alert banners or notifications, just on the billing page itself. GTM server preview started loading again and requests were no longer throwing 500s on the auto created app engine.